# TypeError: movieList.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux, react-typescript

I am using React Typescript and Redux to make a movie app. I managed to set up my Redux store, actions, and reducers. I hooked everything up to my UI and I was hit with the following error:

```
TypeError: movieList.map is not a function
```

this is the code for my app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MovieCard from './components/movieCard';
import SpinnerComponent from './components/spinner';
import {Container, Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {RootState} from './store'
import { getMovies, setLoading } from './store/actions/movieActions'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';



const App = ()=>{
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const movieList = useSelector((state: RootState)=>state.movies.data);
  const loading = useSelector((state: RootState)=>state.movies.loading);
  dispatch(getMovies())
 // dispatch(setLoading());

console.log(movieList);
  return(
  <div className="body">
        <Container fluid >
        { movieList!=null?
     <Row   className='row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-3' >
   {
    
     movieList.map((movie, index)=>(
       <MovieCard movie = {movie} key= {index}>
       </MovieCard>
     ))
   }
  
 </Row>
  
: 
  
<SpinnerComponent>  
  </SpinnerComponent>

}
</Container>
</div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

the code for my movie reducer:

```
import { MoviesState, MovieAction, GET_MOVIES, SET_LOADING, SET_ERROR, } from "../type";

const initialState: MoviesState ={
    data:[],
    loading: false,
    error: '',
}

export default (state = initialState, action: MovieAction):MoviesState=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_MOVIES:
            return{
                data: action.payload,
                loading: false,
                error: ''
            }
        case SET_LOADING:
            return{
                    ...state,
                    loading: true
            }
        case SET_ERROR:
            return{
                ...state,
                error: action.payload,
                loading: false,
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

the code for my actions:

```
import { ThunkAction } from "redux-thunk";
import {RootState} from '..';
import {MovieAction, Results, MoviesError, GET_MOVIES, SET_LOADING,SET_ERROR} from '../type'

export const getMovies = ():ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, MovieAction>=>{
    return async dispatch => {
 try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://localhost:44325/popular`,{
        headers:{
            'ApiKey':`1808BX234TSY`,
        }
    });
    if (!res.ok) {
        const resData: MoviesError = await res.json();
        throw new Error(resData.message);
        
    }
    //console.log(res);
    const resData:Results[] = await res.json();
    // console.log(resData);
    dispatch({
        type: GET_MOVIES,
        payload: resData
    });
 } catch (error) {
    
  if(error instanceof Error){
    dispatch({
        type: SET_ERROR,
        payload: error.message
    })
  }
 }
}
}

export const setLoading = ():MovieAction=>{
    return{
        type:SET_LOADING,
    };
}

export const setError = ():MovieAction=>{
    return{
        type:SET_ERROR,
        payload: ''
    }
}
```

and this is my types.ts:

```
export const GET_MOVIES = 'GET_MOVIES';
export const SET_LOADING = 'SET_LOADING';
export const SET_ERROR = 'SET_ERROR';
export const SET_ALERT = 'SET_ALERT';

export interface Results{
    adult:             boolean;
    backdrop_path:     string;
    id:                number;
    original_language: string;
    original_title:    string;
    overview:          string;
    popularity:        number;
    poster_path:       string;
    release_date:      string;
    title:             string;
    vote_average:      number;
    vote_count:        number;

}

export interface Movies {
    
    results:Results[]
}

export interface MoviesError{
    cod: string;
    message: string;
}

export interface MoviesState{
    data: Results[];
    loading: boolean;
    error: string;
}

interface GetMoviesAction{
    type: typeof GET_MOVIES;
    payload: Results[]
}

interface SetLoadingAction{
    type: typeof SET_LOADING;
}

interface SetErrorAction{
    type: typeof SET_ERROR;
    payload: string;
}

export type MovieAction = GetMoviesAction|SetLoadingAction|SetErrorAction;

export interface AlertAction{
    type: typeof SET_ALERT;
    payload:string
}

export interface AlertState {
    message: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Javascript error. [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a `function` in Javascript that is defined for arrays. It transforms the items of the array by the `function` it receives as a parameter. In order to resolve the issue, you will need to find out what `movieList` is. It is quite possible that it's an object instead of an array.

Comment: its of type ```Result[]|[]```

Comment: @JacobMutale can you share a screenshot of a `console.log` in your question?